# Applescript can't get list

Tags: arrays, while-loop, applescript

So I want this `repeat with` loop to open all the applications in the list `listOfApplications`. I based this code off of multiple scripts that is stored at `/Library/Scripts/Script Editor Scripts/Iterate Items/`. But the Applescript gives me the error message: `Can’t get list {\"Google Chrome\", \"Safari\", \"TextEdit\"}." number -1728 from list {"Google Chrome", "Safari", "TextEdit"}`. I have no idea why and any help would be appreciated.

```
set listOfApplications to {"Google Chrome", "Safari", "TextEdit"}
set applicationsToOpen to every item of list listOfApplications
repeat with i from 1 to the count of applicationsToOpen
    tell application (item i of listOfItems) to launch
end repeat
```

Comment: FYI, there are two redundancies in your code. First, listOfApplications doesn't need to be prefaced with 'list' — just use 'items of listOfApplications' — this is the cause of your error. Secondly, you may notice that the original list and the returned list are identical, so you could work with just listOfApplications (as shown below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't over complicate things... the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will do what it is you are trying to do:

```applescript
set listOfApplications to {"Google Chrome", "Safari", "TextEdit"}

repeat with appName in listOfApplications
    tell application appName to launch
end repeat
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>